# "firebase deploy --only hosting" suddenly failing with "Error: Failed to list functions for <PROJECT>"

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

My firebase hosting deployments have suddenly started failing both in my Github CI Workflows and from my local machine.

```
$ firebase deploy --only hosting

=== Deploying to '<project>'...

i  deploying hosting

Error: Failed to list functions for <project>
```

The project in question does not have any functions, and only hosts a static site. Google searches for "Failed to list functions" turn up empty, it seems like not a common problem. The only leads I can find indicate some kind of network error.

I have updated my firebase-tools, logged out and in again to generate a new CI token, tried the process from my Github workflows and also manually from my machine, all to the same effect.

I can't find any information about this problem, except that the error seems to come from this part of the firebase-tools codebase:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/c0f19a32845135108c75a1050024965cb1e3f52d/src/gcp/cloudfunctions.ts

Answer (score 13):

My firebase tools version was 11.14.0. I changed that to 11.13.0. Installed this specific version through npm install -g firebase-tools@11.13.0. After that I could successfully deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the issue. using firebase-tools version 10.5 or upgrading it to blaze plan fixed my issue